# Any way to print gcc ld error detail

Tags: gcc

I want to add a library to my code. so when I compile it, I use -l option. but gcc terminate with ld error. I even try to use pkg-config to generate gcc flags, but these flags are still not working.

So, I think I need a solution to get the real information about this error, how can I make gcc to print ld error details?

other compiler like clang++ can do this work is OK, too.

Comment: You really should show us the error, and possibly the failing `gcc` command (or the `Makefile` rules triggering it).

Answer (score 1):

`ld` is part of *binutils*, and accept [many options](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/ld/Options.html). Maybe you want to pass `--verbose` to it.

`gcc` is running `ld` and also has [link options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html). Pass `-v` to `gcc` to get the exact `ld` command it is running.

Maybe you should link with `gcc -v -Wl,--verbose`

Comment: Thank you! This tips works. Though the output is still not very readable. Finally, I find my problem comes from missing of library.